# Drawing on jupyter notebooks on DataSpell

Tags: python, canvas, jupyter-notebook, dataspell

I know this is "seeking for recommendations", but I have no experience with this.

I'm looking for a library for basic drawing in jupyter notebooks.
In particular I don't want libraries like `plotly` or  `matplotlib`, since I don't need to draw graphs.

I'm looking for something like Canvas for JS.

I've already tested `ipycanvas` and `tkinter` but they don't work on DataSpell:
[image]

Comment: I think the title of your post would be improved by adding 'DataSpell' to it. 'Drawing on jupyter notebooks' as a title is way too broad for what you describe in the post.

Comment: @Wayne yep, done it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package `turtle` to produce drawings in Python.

Comment: yes but it opens a new window, I want the plot to stay on the notebook, just like matplotlib

Comment: So would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778173/make-turtle-graphics-inline) help?

Comment: no, it uses the same render engine as ipycanvas, which does not work

Comment: Ah, sorry about that!

Comment: no worries, thanks for the time you are taking to help me